# manual utm parameter not recognized in GA with magento website

Tags: google-analytics, magento-1.9, utm

I'm having very hard time getting my GA to recognize the manual utm parameters put into my website's home page.
I was testing with this url:

The website is built with Magento 1.9.

The potential problem might be caused by URL rewrite. When I load my website using the above url, the url changes (gets overwritten) with just rheafootwear.com.

Thanks in advance.